# Can I open other files without closing the file I'm editing?

Tags: buffers

I'm new to vi/vim.

I learned that I can close a file I'm editing and open the another file at once by typing `:vi filename`

But I sometimes want to open other files without closing the file I'm editing and interchange these buffers with commands like `:next` or `:prev`

Can I do that?

(I haven't understand the difference among `buffer`, `window` and `file` exactly yet. So some words could be wrong I used avobe.)

my vim's version is 7.2, Small version without GUI and be used on CentOS6.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I want to recommend that you go through the vimtutor (`:h tutor`). That will explain a lot of the different concepts in Vim. To learn about the difference between the buffers, windows and a file, you can read for instance: `:h windows.txt` and `:h editing.txt`.

The command `:vi` or `:visual` is used to get out of ex mode and back to normal mode. If you don't know what ex mode is, then I suggest you instead use the command `:e ...` to edit new files.

If you want to close a file, but leave the buffer open, I suggest that you use the option `:set hidden`. See `:h 'hidden'` for a detailed explanation. In short, this will set closed buffers to hidden instead of wiping them. Thus you can reopen closed files with `:bnext` and `:bprev` and similar.

Comment: Great answer. Hidden buffers is closest to what the question described: I like to use tabs for any unsaved buffers without `:set hidden`, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I use `:ls` to list the buffers open and `:b  <filename_from_list_of_open_buffers>` to edit it.

n.b. `:b` auto completes so I just start typing and bash the tab key until the file displayed is correct.

If I want to open a new buffer, I use `e: <filename>`. I am by no means a vim expert so the terminology might be wrong.